# "Кукситься" — происхождение

Tags: этимология

"Кукситься" — хандрить, дуться. А какая у этого слова этимология?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кукситься - быть в плохом настроении или недомогать; хандрить.
Исконно русское слово. Образовано от глагола "куксить", известного в диалектах в значении "тереть глаза кулаками" и являющегося производным от "кукса" - "плакса". Слово "кукса" образовано от глагола "кукати" - "горевать, плакать" (ср. "докука", "скука").